# Memory corruption with concurrent_queue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, concurrency, c++11

I've got a problem with memory corruption in my concurrent system.

I've got a memory allocator which is not thread-safe, and I'm attempting to make it thread-safe by serving up multiple instances to various threads on-demand. This code shows the system I'm using. It effectively builds a queue of instances. If the queue is empty, a fresh instance is created, else one is taken off the queue. When the thread is done with the instance, it pushes it back into the queue to be used again later.

```
Concurrency::concurrent_queue<std::shared_ptr<Memory::Arena>> result_memory_arenas;
//std::
struct ConcurrentMemoryArena {
    Context* ptr;
    std::shared_ptr<Memory::Arena> arena;
    Memory::Arena& operator*() { return *arena; }
    Memory::Arena* operator->() { return arena.get(); }
    ~ConcurrentMemoryArena() {
        if (arena)
            ptr->result_memory_arenas.push(arena);
    }
    ConcurrentMemoryArena(Context* owner)
        : ptr(owner) {}
    ConcurrentMemoryArena(ConcurrentMemoryArena&& other) {
        arena = std::move(other.arena);
        other.arena = nullptr;
        ptr = other.ptr;
    }
};
ConcurrentMemoryArena ConcurrentGetResultArena() {
    ConcurrentMemoryArena ret(this);
    /*if (!result_memory_arenas.empty()) {
        ret.arena = result_memory_arenas.front();
        result_memory_arenas.pop();
        return ret;
    }*/
    if (result_memory_arenas.try_pop(ret.arena)) {
        return ret;
    }
    ret.arena = std::make_shared<Memory::Arena>();
    return std::move(ret);
}
```

My using code is fairly small.

```
Concurrency::concurrent_vector<Wide::Parser::NamespaceAST*> ASTs;
Concurrency::parallel_for_each(filenames.begin(), filenames.end(), [&](String* ptr) {
    auto arena = ConcurrentGetResultArena();
    ASTs.push_back(parser(lexer(ptr, *arena), *arena));
});
```

Both `lexer` and `parser` are "pure" functions and not concurrent in any way or shared state.

The system works fine, but when this function is finished, the memory is nuked, and by that I mean the whole object containing `result_memory_arenas`, and when the queue destructs, then it tries to destroy `shared_ptr`s which have invalid pointers, causing a crash. But I can't see where the problem is coming from. I've used pre-provided concurrent containers, `shared_ptr` is thread-safe, and the functions which are actually called in parallel are pure.

Edit: The other objects were dead because, funnily enough, the queue is actually the last thing to be destroyed. I broke on adding to the queue and they're all valid `shared_ptr`'s. When the function is finished, *they're all valid `shared_ptr`s*. So how come when destroying the queue, it destroys a bust `shared_ptr`?

Edit again: I traced it to an uninitialized memory bug in the implementation, which doesn't surprise me terribly. It's amazing that this stuff passed any kind of test with non-POD classes.

Comment: is result_memory_arenas thread-safe?  (I don't see the type)  does it own the objects inside or is it owned elsewhere?  valgrind's drd and helgrind will also help you detect errors.

Comment: @kfmfe04: It owns all the objects inside, and it's a specialist container intended for concurrent use. The type is right up there on the first line.

Comment: btw... is your code correct for ConcurrentGetResultArena? It contains a this pointer which means it should be a class method, but you wrote it as a stand-alone function. Copy paste error?

Comment: @CJohnson: No, it's just only part of the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Traced this one to an implementation bug, again. Microsoft should hire me as a tester.

Comment: Did you post a bug report on [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/)? If so, can you post a link here so we can upvote it?